# Sidekick activation greyed out (CQ 5.4)

Tags: acl, aem

i'm Setting up a local CQ Author instance for dev/testing.
After applying some Hotfixes the activation button within the sidekick is greyed out.
Logged in as admin user, i can activate the page via WCM.
Checked the ACLs but no suspicious Settings found.

[image: Sidekick]
[image: ACL Apps]
[image: ACL Content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was an overlay which had a false ACL checking within.